Tracking test/val loss when training a model with JAX
JAX when being used for training a machine learning model, we only try to minimize the training loss.
Whereas in my requirement, in order to assess the number of epochs or to avoid over-training, I need to know the test loss as well at every parameter update step. But the callback or debug option available in JAX explicitly suggests that I shouldn't be doing any compute intensive tasks, like finding the test loss and accuracy.
The below optimization works flawless
import pennylane as qml
from pennylane import numpy as np
import jax
from jax import numpy as jnp
import optax
from itertools import combinations
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
np.random.seed(42)
import time

# Load the digits dataset with features (X_digits) and labels (y_digits)
X_digits, y_digits = load_digits(return_X_y=True)

# Create a boolean mask to filter out only the samples where the label is 2 or 6
filter_mask = np.isin(y_digits, [2, 6])

# Apply the filter mask to the features and labels to keep only the selected digits
X_digits = X_digits[filter_mask]
y_digits = y_digits[filter_mask]

# Split the filtered dataset into training and testing sets with 10% of data reserved for testing
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X_digits, y_digits, test_size=0.1, random_state=42
)

# Normalize the pixel values in the training and testing data
# Convert each image from a 1D array to an 8x8 2D array, normalize pixel values, and scale them
X_train = np.array([thing.reshape([8, 8]) / 16 * 2 * np.pi for thing in X_train])
X_test = np.array([thing.reshape([8, 8]) / 16 * 2 * np.pi for thing in X_test])

# Adjust the labels to be centered around 0 and scaled to be in the range -1 to 1
# The original labels (2 and 6) are mapped to -1 and 1 respectively
y_train = (y_train - 4) / 2
y_test = (y_test - 4) / 2


def feature_map(features):
    # Apply Hadamard gates to all qubits to create an equal superposition state
    for i in range(len(features[0])):
        qml.Hadamard(i)

    # Apply angle embeddings based on the feature values
    for i in range(len(features)):
        # For odd-indexed features, use Z-rotation in the angle embedding
        if i % 2:
            qml.AngleEmbedding(features=features[i], wires=range(8), rotation="Z")
        # For even-indexed features, use X-rotation in the angle embedding
        else:
            qml.AngleEmbedding(features=features[i], wires=range(8), rotation="X")

# Define the ansatz (quantum circuit ansatz) for parameterized quantum operations
def ansatz(params):
    # Apply RY rotations with the first set of parameters
    for i in range(8):
        qml.RY(params[i], wires=i)

    # Apply CNOT gates with adjacent qubits (cyclically connected) to create entanglement
    for i in range(8):
        qml.CNOT(wires=[(i - 1) % 8, (i) % 8])

    # Apply RY rotations with the second set of parameters
    for i in range(8):
        qml.RY(params[i + 8], wires=i)

    # Apply CNOT gates with qubits in reverse order (cyclically connected)
    # to create additional entanglement
    for i in range(8):
        qml.CNOT(wires=[(8 - 2 - i) % 8, (8 - i - 1) % 8])



dev = qml.device("default.qubit", wires=8)


@qml.qnode(dev)
def circuit(params, features):
    feature_map(features)
    ansatz(params)
    return qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(0))


def variational_classifier(weights, bias, x):
    return circuit(weights, x) + bias


def square_loss(labels, predictions):
    return np.mean((labels - qml.math.stack(predictions)) ** 2)


def accuracy(labels, predictions):
    acc = sum([np.sign(l) == np.sign(p) for l, p in zip(labels, predictions)])
    acc = acc / len(labels)
    return acc


def cost(params, X, Y):
    predictions = [variational_classifier(params["weights"], params["bias"], x) for x in X]
    return square_loss(Y, predictions)


def acc(params, X, Y):
    predictions = [variational_classifier(params["weights"], params["bias"], x) for x in X]
    return accuracy(Y, predictions)


np.random.seed(0)
weights = 0.01 * np.random.randn(16)
bias = jnp.array(0.0)
params = {"weights": weights, "bias": bias}
opt = optax.adam(0.05)
batch_size = 7
num_batch = X_train.shape[0] // batch_size
opt_state = opt.init(params)
X_batched = X_train.reshape([-1, batch_size, 8, 8])
y_batched = y_train.reshape([-1, batch_size])


@jax.jit
def update_step_jit(i, args):
    params, opt_state, data, targets, batch_no, print_training = args
    _data = data[batch_no % num_batch]
    _targets = targets[batch_no % num_batch]
    loss_val, grads = jax.value_and_grad(cost)(params, _data, _targets)
    updates, opt_state = opt.update(grads, opt_state)
    params = optax.apply_updates(params, updates)

    # Print training loss every 5 steps if print_training is True
    def print_fn():
        jax.debug.print("Step: {i}, Train Loss: {loss_val}", i=i, loss_val=loss_val)

    jax.lax.cond((jnp.mod(i, 1) == 0) & print_training, print_fn, lambda: None)
    return (params, opt_state, data, targets, batch_no + 1, print_training)


@jax.jit
def optimization_jit(params, data, targets, print_training = True):
    opt_state = opt.init(params)
    args = (params, opt_state, data, targets, 0, print_training)
    (params, opt_state, _, _, _, _) = jax.lax.fori_loop(0, 10, update_step_jit, args)
    return params

start_time = time.time()
params = optimization_jit(params, X_batched, y_batched)
print("Training Done! \nTime taken:",time.time() - start_time)

var_train_acc = acc(params, X_train, y_train)
print("Training accuracy: ", var_train_acc)

var_test_acc = acc(params, X_test, y_test)
print("Testing accuracy: ", var_test_acc)

Although inefficient, I tried to include more compute in the print_fn() function as:
@jax.jit
def update_step_jit(i, args):
    params, opt_state, data, targets, batch_no, print_training = args
    _data = data[batch_no % num_batch]
    _targets = targets[batch_no % num_batch]
    loss_val, grads = jax.value_and_grad(cost)(params, _data, _targets)
    updates, opt_state = opt.update(grads, opt_state)
    params = optax.apply_updates(params, updates)

    def print_fn():
        jax.debug.print("Step: {i}, Train Loss: {loss_val}", i=i, loss_val=loss_val)

        # Calculate accuracy and loss for training and test sets
        train_accuracy = acc(params, X_train, y_train)
        test_predictions = jnp.array([variational_classifier(params["weights"], params["bias"], x) for x in X_test])
        test_loss = square_loss(y_test, test_predictions)
        test_accuracy = accuracy(y_test, test_predictions)

        jax.debug.print("Step: {i}, Train Accuracy {train_accuracy}", i=i, train_accuracy = train_accuracy)
        jax.debug.print("Step: {i}, Test Accuracy {test_accuracy}", i=i, test_accuracy = test_accuracy)
        jax.debug.print("Step: {i}, Test Loss {test_loss}", i=i, test_loss = test_loss)

    # if print_training=True, print the loss every 5 steps
    jax.lax.cond((jnp.mod(i, 1) == 0) & print_training, print_fn, lambda: None)
    return (params, opt_state, data, targets, batch_no + 1, print_training)


@jax.jit
def optimization_jit(params, data, targets, print_training = False):
    opt_state = opt.init(params)
    args = (params, opt_state, data, targets, 0, print_training)
    (params, opt_state, _, _, _, _) = jax.lax.fori_loop(0, 10, update_step_jit, args)
    return params


params = optimization_jit(params, X_batched, y_batched, print_training = True)
var_train_acc = acc(params, X_train, y_train)
var_test_acc = acc(params, X_test, y_test)

print("Training accuracy: ", var_train_acc)
print("Testing accuracy: ", var_test_acc)

It gives me a weird error like:
TracerArrayConversionError: The numpy.ndarray conversion method __array__() was called on traced array with shape float32[]
The error occurred while tracing the function print_fn at C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_43468\2623796165.py:10 for cond. This value became a tracer due to JAX operations on these lines:

  operation a:f32[1] = slice[limit_indices=(1,) start_indices=(0,) strides=None] b
    from line C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_43468\1231864253.py:61:15 (ansatz)

  operation a:f32[1] = slice[limit_indices=(2,) start_indices=(1,) strides=None] b
    from line C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_43468\1231864253.py:61:15 (ansatz)

  operation a:f32[1] = slice[limit_indices=(3,) start_indices=(2,) strides=None] b
    from line C:\Users\mysore\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_43468\1231864253.py:61:15 (ansatz)

  operation a:f32[1] = slice[limit_indices=(4,) start_indices=(3,) strides=None] b
    from line C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_43468\1231864253.py:61:15 (ansatz)

  operation a:f32[1] = slice[limit_indices=(5,) start_indices=(4,) strides=None] b
    from line C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_43468\1231864253.py:61:15 (ansatz)

(Additional originating lines are not shown.)

My training time would drastically increase if I don't use JAX.
So, with JAX, I can get the performance on the test set only at the end of the training, and there's no way I can get the test losses in the middle of the training or is there a workaround for this?
For a minimal reproducable example, you can try to run the example given in this demo code.

When running your code, I get TypeError: optimization_jit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'print_training'. If I try deleting this argument from the function call, I get NameError: name 'feature_map' is not defined.

I have added the functions feature_map and ansatz

OK, now I'm getting name errors on X_train_ndarray and y_train_ndarray – these variables are not defined. Please try running your code in a fresh environment to make sure everything is there!

@jakevdp I edited again and have made sure it's reproducible in a new environment.

Looking at this part of the traceback:
<ipython-input-2-41bf687aa445> in <listcomp>(.0)
     97 def accuracy(labels, predictions):
---> 98     acc = sum([np.sign(l) == np.sign(p) for l, p in zip(labels, predictions)])
    100     return acc

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pennylane/numpy/wrapper.py in _wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    116         # evaluate the original object
--> 117         res = obj(*args, **kwargs)
    118 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/autograd/tracer.py in f_wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     47         else:
---> 48             return f_raw(*args, **kwargs)
     50     f_wrapped._is_autograd_primitive = True

it appears your accuracy function is incompatible with JAX transformations, because pennylane.numpy.sign dispatches to numpy.sign, which attempts to convert the traced value to an array.
The best solution here would be to rewrite your accuracy function in a way that is compatible with JAX, for example:
def accuracy(labels, predictions):
    acc = sum([jnp.sign(l) == jnp.sign(p) for l, p in zip(labels, predictions)])
    acc = acc / len(labels)
    return acc

Using this accuracy function, I no longer see an error, although after half an hour the function has not finished executing, so you have some efficiency problems in the implementation: I suspect your use of Python's built-in sum and Python list comprehensions is probably to blame, since these are iterative methods that can lead to long runtimes for JAX programs.

As pointed out by @jakevdp, there is an issue with the efficiency in running the function accuracy due to operations that are not JAX native.
Although, I tried to ensure only JAX arrays and fully vectorized operation for compatibility as below;
def accuracy(labels, predictions):
    labels = jnp.array(labels)
    predictions = jnp.array(predictions)
    correct_predictions = jnp.sign(labels) == jnp.sign(predictions)
    acc = jnp.mean(correct_predictions)
    return acc

but still the performance in evaluating accuracy is very bad, infact it's infeasible.
As I am dealing with Quantum Neural Networks, in specific Parameterized Quantum Ciruits as my model, the number of learnable parameters are very few in number. Thus, a more feasible and efficient workaround would be to log the train and test loss (surprisingly the evaluation of test loss is not very slow), atleast this helps in avoiding overfitting.
Furthermore, for getting the accuracies, save the parameters at each step using jax.debug.callback, and fetch them to calculate the train and test accuracies at each step after the training process.
It can be implemented as below.
import os
import pickle
import time
from datetime import datetime

def save_params(params, step):
    # Get current timestamp
    current_timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    # Directory where params are saved
    dir_path = f"stackoverflow_logs/{current_timestamp}/params"
    os.makedirs(dir_path, exist_ok=True)  # Create directories if they don't exist

    # File path for saving params at the current step
    file_path = os.path.join(dir_path, f"{step}.pkl")
    
    # Save params using pickle
    with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(params, f)
    print(f"Parameters saved at step {step} to {file_path}")


@jax.jit
def update_step_jit(i, args):
    params, opt_state, data, targets, X_test, y_test, X_train, y_train, batch_no, print_training = args
    _data = data[batch_no % num_batch]
    _targets = targets[batch_no % num_batch]
    train_loss, grads = jax.value_and_grad(cost)(params, _data, _targets)
    updates, opt_state = opt.update(grads, opt_state)
    test_loss, _ = jax.value_and_grad(cost)(params, jnp.array(X_test), jnp.array(y_test))
    # Save parameters every step
    jax.debug.callback(lambda params, step: save_params(params, step), params, i)
    params = optax.apply_updates(params, updates)

    def print_fn():
        jax.debug.print("Step: {i}, Train Loss: {train_loss}, Test Loss: {test_loss}", i=i, train_loss=train_loss, test_loss=test_loss)

    jax.lax.cond((jnp.mod(i, 1) == 0) & print_training, print_fn, lambda: None)
    return (params, opt_state, data, targets, X_test, y_test, X_train, y_train, batch_no + 1, print_training)

@jax.jit
def optimization_jit(params, data, targets, X_test, y_test, X_train, y_train, print_training = True):
    opt_state = opt.init(params)
    args = (params, opt_state, data, targets, X_test, y_test, X_train, y_train, 0, print_training)
    (params, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _) = jax.lax.fori_loop(0, 10, update_step_jit, args)
    return params

params = optimization_jit(params, X_batched, y_batched, X_test, y_test, X_train, y_train)

var_train_acc = acc(params, X_train, y_train)
var_test_acc = acc(params, X_test, y_test)

print("Training accuracy: ", var_train_acc)
print("Testing accuracy: ", var_test_acc)

Finally, one can also use any frameworks like wandb, mlflow or aim for tracking in the callback function.
